# Is it possible to use PostHog as a "user feedback dashboard"?

Tags: posthog

I was thinking of using PostHog to track events like "Thumbs up" / "Thumbs down" but one of the challenges is that a user can change their selection over time. So what I am trying to track is the latest "Thumbs up" / "Thumbs down" per user and do a count for all users.

I saw that Dashboard seems to support HogQL but I did not find a lot of documentation of it and was unable to make it work.

Is what I am trying to do even feasible using PostHog?